# Woocommerce: auto add product to cart by user meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I need to automatically add a product to the cart after user registration (which worked) but to decide which product to add by the user meta (which doesn't work).

The first action was just to add a product after registration and it worked perfectly:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = 115;
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a specific product according to lists I have of users promoID I got, but it doesn't add anything to the cart. 
example of the code:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {

        $group1iid1 = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
        $group1iid2 = array("5", "6", "7", "8");

        if (in_array("2", $group1iid1)) {
            $product_id = 115;
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } elseif (in_array("0", $group1iid2)) {
            $product_id = 219;
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );

        } else {
            $product_id = 231;
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

If I take the code to a template file and just echo something instead of adding a product - it works ok, but when it's like this in the function.php > nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There are missing things in your code:

1. In your first condition you need also to add [**`is_user_logged_in()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) condition, as I suppose that this code is for new registrated users only.
2. You need to get for **the current user, HIS Promo ID value**. I suppose that this value is set in user metadata, so to get this Promo ID value with [**`get_user_meta()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) function, you have to define the correct **`meta_key`**.
3. In your code you have to replace in your conditions **`'2'`** and **`'0'`** values **by the current user Promo ID**… 
   *(Also **`elseif (in_array("0", $group1iid2)) {`** condition is going to be always **false** as **`"0"`** value doesn't exist in **`$group1iid2`**)*

As I can't test for real all this, Here is some kind of work around, based on your code *(without any guaranty)*:

```
 add_action( 'user_register', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $user_id > 0 ) {
        
        // DEFINE BELOW THE META KEY TO GET THE VALUE FOR YOUR GROUP OF CURRENT USER
        $meta_key = 'your_group_meta_key';
        
        // Getting the current user group ID
        $user_promo_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true );

        $group1_id1 = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
        $group1_id2 = array('5', '6', '7', '8');
        
        if (in_array( $user_promo_id, $group1_id1 ) ) {
            $product_id = 115;
        } elseif (in_array( $user_promo_id, $group1_id2 ) ) {
            $product_id = 219;
        } else {
            $product_id = 231;
        } 

        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }
}
```

Comment: the "0" supposed to not be in the array in this example. the promoID will appear only in one group of ID's.

Comment: + the users are registered and auto login afterwords. they actually can't get to this page anyway else.
I'll give your example a try soon and report back. thanks!